# android backup service integration with third party service provider

Tags: android, cloud

as we all know the default back service provider is google in android. Now i wan to use some other backup service provider. How is it possible. 
When you go in setting-> back-up synch section, add account, there are some predefined list of service provider available. If i want to add my service provider, how can i?
do i need to do something in my app, to add other third party service provider.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If i want to add my service provider, how can i?

Build your own ROM mod that has a modified version of the Android OS in it, and install that ROM mod on devices.

There is no support in the Android SDK to define alternative backup providers, unfortunately. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html):

> The backup transport is the client-side component of Android's backup framework, which is customizable by the device manufacturer and service provider.

Comment: but in the same link they are saying "Register your application with a backup service. Google offers Android Backup Service as a backup service for most Android-powered devices, which requires that you register your application in order for it to work. Any other backup services available might also require you to register in order to store your data on their servers."                                           so it's not possible at application level.

Comment: @ManishaKhare: "Any other backup services available might also require you to register in order to store your data on their servers" -- and those are set up "by the device manufacturer and service provider", not you or me, unless we make our own ROM. I really wish there was some way that users could choose other backup providers, besides whatever ones happen to come on the device.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, ohh, that's very sad. My requirement was to create a backup through some other service provider, and if it is not possible at application level, then it will be difficult for me. Can we change at framework level, or at android file system. Is there any way, at that level also i can try.

Comment: @ManishaKhare: In theory, you can change it at the framework level, by building your own ROM mod that has a modified version of the Android OS in it, and installing that ROM mod on devices, as I mentioned in my answer. You are also welcome to do your own backups outside of the `BackupManager`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, Google’s solution is just a bad reinvention of the wheel, and Android’s Linux core can happily use the solutions that existed for decades.

The usual solution on Unix/Linux/BSD systems, is to run a `cron` job, using `rsync` over an encrypted connection (e.g. `ssh`), which is readily available or super-easy to install on any Linux server, and probably any other system as well. (If you don’t know those programs, try `man <command>`, or search for their man pages online.)

There are **rsync apps** for Android. And I’ve seen at least one that could do ssh and (as is usual) didn’t require rsync to be installed on the server.
If one of them allows setting a schedule, or supports the **Tasker** app (which also allows automating it), you’re good.

There’s **FolderSync** too, which supports all combinations of SSH and FTP and many other protocols. But probably doesn’t have the freedom that a true rsync command offers.

Finally, **SyncThing** seems to fit the category too, but I don’t know if it can be scheduled, and haven’t tried it.

If you sync through an untrusted network, make sure that the app supports not only having the server verify the client, but the client verifying the server too! (Using public keys and/or certificates.)